# Pipeline job state change webhook

Tags: azure-devops

I need to react to state changes of a pipeline's **job**.

I see in the [Azure DevOps Services service hooks events docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#run.stagestatechanged) that there are 2 event types for **stage** changes (Run state changed & Run stage state changed).

Are there any similar events that trigger when state changes at the **job** level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I am afraid you could not configure the event type at `job` level.

All the supported event types are listed here - [Available event types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#available-event-types), if you want to improve this, you could request a feature for Azure DevOps [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=21&preview2=true).

Comment: That's what I'm seeing yes.

Comment: @IvanAguilar Yes, you could request the feature in the link I provided.

Comment: Thanks for the info, already requested the feature!